# Vieta's Formula modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This problem was given without answer in a book by Vinogradov (Fundamentals of number theory). I find it nice and maybe useful for beginners because it raises modulo $p$  an analogy with the well-known Vieta's formula  in elemental algebra.

Assume that $$a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n\equiv0\pmod p$$ admits n solutions.

Prove that $$a_i\equiv (-1)^i a_0S_i; 1\le i\le n$$ where the $S_i$'s are the Vieta's coefficients (the elementary symmetric polynomials)

Comment: Does the proof of the usual Vieta formula use any step that wouldn't be valid modulo $p$?

Comment: @Will Jagy.-I don't think Vinogradov is wrong in this detail and I think that admitting $n$ solutions fixes that apparent slip. Regards.

Comment: @Greg Martin.-My goal is information for beginners. I bet at least one will see this result with well-being.

Comment: Can one take for granted that the polynomial can be rewritten as $a_0(x-\alpha_1)…(x-\alpha_n)$ where the $\alpha$s are the n solutions ?

Comment: @Thomas.-Good but in rigor one should consider when some $S_k(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n)$ put (apparent problems modulo $p$.

Comment: Mmm... I am not sure I am getting it. You mean that the factorization I wrote is not valid ?